# Can any one please tell me proper way to Develop Separate Undefined component in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

**ReactJs**

I am trying to create separate reusable Undefined Component to handle undefined properties but initially its comes with undefined so passed children throwing "Cant read property error" 
here is the component

Final Aim = how to show children  only if the passed property  not undefined

```
 <CanUndefined property={schedules.review} message="Yet you dont have any reviews">
      <span>{schedules.review.message}</span>
 </CanUndefined>
```

bellow component is **ParentComponent**

```
const CanUndefined = props => props.property ? 
                             (props.children) : 
                             (<span>
                                 {props.message}
                              </span>)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your component around condition,

e.g.

you want to display div tag if message is there than

```
const {message} = source of your property;
if(message){
   <span>{message}</span>
}

or even short format

{message && (
   <span>{message}</span>
)}
```

Comment: thnak you for the quick reply ... and i need to write data accroding to deffrent situtation so i would like to mannage it instead passing as children every  time ...i already done as shown above... my  if property exists only render children otherwise not   in that situation rendering it as children in usable component

Answer (score 0):

You will need to test explicitly for the value. Try this:

```
const CanUndefined = props => {
    if(props.property === undefined){ 
        return props.children
    }
    return <span>
        {props.message}
    </span>
```